# matplotlib - How can I use MaxNLocator and specify a number which has to be in an axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axis

I do have a question with matplotlib in python. I create different figures, where every figure should have the same height to print them in a publication/poster next to each other.

If the y-axis has a label on the very top, this shrinks the height of the box with the plot. So I use MaxNLocator to remove the upper and lower y-tick. In some plots, I want to have the 1.0 as a number on the y-axis, because I have normalized data. So I need a solution, which expands in these cases the y-axis and ensures 1.0 is a y-Tick, but does not corrupt the size of the figure using tight_layout().

Here is a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

x = np.linspace(0,1,num=11)
y = np.linspace(1,.42,num=11)

fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,1)
axs.plot(x,y)

locator=MaxNLocator(prune='both',nbins=5)
axs.yaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

plt.tight_layout()

fig.show()
```

Here is a [link](https://depot.uni-konstanz.de/cgi-bin/exchange.pl?g=n4hq3y25kt) to a example-pdf, which shows the problems with height of upper boxline.

I tried to work with adjust_subplots() but this is of no use for me, because I vary the size of the figures and want to have same the font size all the time, which changes the margins.

Question is:

How can I use MaxNLocator and specify a number which has to be in the y-axis?

Hopefully someone of you has some advice.

Greetings,
Laenan

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Maybe you can post a screenshot and explain the undesired result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. See the pdf-File: [link](https://depot.uni-konstanz.de/cgi-bin/exchange.pl?g=n4hq3y25kt) (cannot post picture, low reputation)

Problem is, that if both graphics (with and without MaxNLocator) are printet next to each other, the layout is corrupted (upper box line is not inline).

For this I used MaxNLocator. Question is, how can I use MaxNLocator and  have e.g. 1.0 as a y-tick-label, too?

Comment: Why don't you just add the ytick for 1.0? I mean, something like: `axs.set_yticks(np.append(axs.get_yticks(), [1.0]))`

Comment: @valtuarte: Of course, this will work, but with the tight_layout() this could cause different heights of the upper boxline, too. (see link in question) And besides it will lead to uneven spaces between ticks.

Nevertheless this is a good idea, I tried to fix it with adding some space with:

`y_ticks=axs.get_yticks()

y_spacing=y_ticks[1]-y_ticks[0]

y_lim=axs.get_ylim()

axs.set_ylim(axs.get_ylim()[0],y_lim[1]+0.5*y_spacing)`

But this does not work for every plot with different data sets.

Comment: What about adding  `bin_boundaries=(min(y), 1.0))` as an additional param to the call to `MaxNLocator`?

Comment: @valtuarte: Tried this as well, but didn't understand the function. Even if i set bin_boundaries=(min(y),2.0), either in function call or by `locator.bin_boundaries(min(y),2.0)` this changes nothing in the output. I also played with `tick_values` and `view_limits`, but couldn't see any changes. And I couldn't find a useful documentation for these functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you know in advance how many plots there will be in 1 row on a page one way to solve this would be to put all those plots into one figure - `matplotlib` will make sure they are aligned on axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=11)
y = np.linspace(1, .42, num=11)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,3), gridspec_kw={'wspace':.2})
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x,y)

locator=MaxNLocator(prune='both', nbins=5)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(locator)

# You don't need to use tight_layout and using it might give an error
# plt.tight_layout()  

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This would solve the problem in general.
I would like to include the figures in TeX separately with different captions, so this is not a solution for me.

Comment: Because it solves the question in general, answer accepted.